# Unable to find a javac compiler com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath error

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I am trying to run java application and I am getting following error,

> Unable to find a javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on
>   the classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK

I have gone through many SO questions and found solution is **JAVA_HOME should be point to JDK, not JRE**.

Then I have tried to print JAVA_HOME in command prompt,

[image]

I had set this JAVA_HOME from my computer->properties->env variables -> system vars as below,

[image]

I had also added new variable in eclipse using preferences as,

[image]

And finally I am still getting the same error. Whats wrong with JAVA_HOME ?

> Update :

In `eclipse-preferences-installed jres` there is only one entry is present and which is jdk and selected,

[image]

And under `project properties` `java build path`-`libraries` there is `JRE System Liberary [jdk1.8.0_31]` is used.

[image]

> Update 1 :

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` have folder named `jre`. Is that `jre` folder causing this issue ? Can I remove this folder ? Is there is any way to add only jdk liberary in project ?

Comment: Pleas confirm whether you started a new console after setting variables or not ? If it was a new console than to me everything else looks clean and correct, I suggest you uninstall and reinstall java ? Sometimes installation errors are there. Use .msi or .exe file to install rather than copy pasting folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eclipse is an IDE and as such, it has (at least) two Java versions: The one which it uses itself to run (`JAVA_HOME`) and a JVM which it uses to run your application. The two don't need to be the same.

So to fix your problem, you need to look into Eclipse's preferences, specifically `Installed JREs` which gives you a list of Java VMs which Eclipse will use to run Java code from projects. My guess is that there will be several entries there and the default will be a JRE instead of a JDK.

Make sure you have a JDK in the list and then go to your project. In the project, you can select which Java VM to use under `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries`.

**[EDIT]**
Look closely at the last screenshot: You've configured Eclipse to use `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre` which means you've pointed it at the JRE inside of the JDK. Use `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` instead (without the `\jre` at the end).

**[EDIT 2]** If you delete the `jre` folder, Java will stop working. Any JDK also contains a JRE. The JRE contains `rt.jar` with `String.class` and the like. The Java compiler is in `tools.jar` which is in the JDK.

If recreating the JRE entry in Eclipse doesn't help, you'll have to add it manually to the classpath.

You can use a variable ("Add Variable...") to make sure Eclipse updates the path when you switch to a new/different JRE. Try `JAVA_HOME` with the extension `lib/tools.jar`

Comment: See my edits; You've selected the JRE inside of the JDK.

Comment: Okay. I'm missing `tools.jar` in the list. Does it exist in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib\tools.jar`?

Comment: Yes `tools.jar` is exists in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib`

Comment: In that case, Eclipse somehow got confused. Delete the JRE in the preferences and add it again with the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`. It should take a few JARs from `...\jre\lib`  (like `rt.jar` which contains `String.class`, for example) but it should also list `...\lib\tools.jar`.

Comment: I have tried to remove JRE in the preferences and add it again with the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`. `rt.jar` is added but there is no existence of `tools.jar`

Comment: :-/ I was sure that Eclipse would add it. In that case, manually add it to the classpath. You can use a variable ("Add Variable...") to make sure Eclipse updates the path when you switch to a new/different JRE. Try `JRE_LIB`. You can use `/../` to go up one level if you have to: `JRE_LIB/../../lib/tools.jar`

Answer (score 5):

1. In Eclipse click Run->External Tools->External Tools Configurations
2. Click JRE tab
3. Click Installed JREs... button
4. Click Add button (select Standard VM, where applicable)
5. Click Directory Button
6. Browse to your JDK version (not JRE) of your installed Java (eg: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04)
7. Click Finish.
8. Re-run Ant script - have fun!

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue while i was using ant from command prompt and the solution which I found is that you need to put tools.jar inside bin folder which is present inside apache ant folder.

For eg :-
D:\apache-ant-1.10.12-bin\lib

You will get tools.jar inside
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\lib

Please change the path based on your java installation path.

Comment: This is bad advice.  You don't need to put a copy of the tools.jar file into the Ant "lib" directory.  The correct fix is to make sure that the JAVA_HOME that Ant is using is **correctly** pointing to the JDK installation directory.  In your case it should be set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211".