# Why is Eclipse adding /jre to my JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javac

A colleague installed a new application for me today and has managed to mangle my PATH and my java environments.  I think I have the critical stuff back, but java build in Eclipse (via ant) does not work.  I get the following error:

> Unable to find a javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on
>   the classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is
>   currently set to "C:\Java\jdk\jre"

The really weird thing is that that is *not* what my JAV_HOME is set to!

```
H:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Java\jdk
```

Where is the extra `\jre` coming from?

I have also added `C:\Java\jdk\bin` to my PATH variable, so `javac` *is* on the path:

```
H:\>javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
```

The line in the build.xml which the stack trace points to is a simple javac ant command:

```
<javac source="${webapps.javac_target}" target="${webapps.javac_target}" debug="on" destdir="${classes}" srcdir="${src}">
```

The default Installed JRE has location `C:\Java\jdk` (and this is the one used by this project).  Even the eclipse.ini ensures that Eclipse uses the same JDK with

```
-vm
C:\Java\jdk\bin\javaw.exe
```

Any ideas what I need to set to make this work again?

Comment: Are the contents of the `Installed JREs` preference page as you expect, including the JRE locations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668849/unable-to-find-a-javac-compiler-com-sun-tools-javac-main-is-not-on-the-classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *thought* that the Installed JREs was correct.  I even downloaded a new JDK.  In the end we discovered that it was pointing to the JDK root, not the JRE folder within.  Changing that solved my problem