# what is tools.jar replacement?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have been receiving the following error on Eclipse when O try to build an Ant project

```
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.2"
```

but my JAVA_HOME variable is set to
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10
this is the result of the command
echo %JAVA_HOME%
i really tried a lot to solve this problem ,but i don't know much about eclipse,

I searched some more on the internet and found out that the tools.jar has been removed from the JDK since JDK 9 [link]https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/765mwr/installed_jdk_9_and_my_toolsjar_is_missing/
the question now is why is Eclipse asking for the tools.jar, and what is tools.jar replacement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find a javac compiler com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668849/unable-to-find-a-javac-compiler-com-sun-tools-javac-main-is-not-on-the-classpath)

Comment: @KevinO not really i tried all the solutions in that thread none worked but ,apparently, tools.jar has been removed from the JDK since  JDK 9 [link ]https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/765mwr/installed_jdk_9_and_my_toolsjar_is_missing/ , now the question becomes what is tools.jar replacement ?

Answer (score 4):

In Java 9 and later, the components that were previously in `tools.jar` have been turned onto modules.  For the javac compiler, you need to use the `java.compiler` module.   This is not a simple drop-in replacement.

If you run into problems with a 3rd-party application (such as Ant) that depends on `tools.jar`, you need to upgrade the application to a newer version that is Java 9+ compatible.

According to my reading of the [Apache Ant site](https://ant.apache.org/), that means you need Ant 1.10.x.  Check the site's download page to see what is currently recommended.

Comment: you are right, but it wasn't the ant it was eclipse, i just had to use a version that is compatible with jdk 10, so i  deleted my eclipse and downloaded the latest version of eclipse  photon ,this seem to have  solved the problem,thank you very much for your help

Comment: I have ant version  1.10.5

Comment: It would have been the version of Ant that is embedded in your (old) Eclipse install ... which Eclipse uses to do Ant builds.

Comment: In case it helps anyone: The `java.compiler` module does not contain `javac` itself, but rather _uses_ `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` which the `jdk.compiler` module _provides_.