# Why tools.jar file is not present in JDK 11 folder

Tags: java, jar, java-11

Why tools.jar file is removed in JDK 11?

What are the causes for it? If anyone have any doc can you share of doc removal of tools.jar expected issues and resolution.

Is tools.jar is added in higher versions and what are they?

Comment: Most, if not all, of the code in `tools.jar` was moved into various `jdk.*` modules with the release of Java 9. Those modules are part of the run-time image (or, at least, they are in OpenJDK-based distributions). For example, the [`jdk.compiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.compiler/module-summary.html) module contains the implementation of the `javac` compiler.

Comment: For the same reason `rt.jar` and `jce.jar jsse.jar` and other crypto-provider jars and `charsets.jar localedata.jar cldrdata.jar` and nearly all other jars are removed in all Java 9 up.

Answer (score 3):

> Why tools.jar file is removed in JDK 11 can anyone explain.

It was removed in Java 9 ... as part of the overhaul to implement Modules.  In fact, the entire Java SE Java codebase is now delivered (at runtime) via the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System); see also [Unable to locate tools.jar for Java SE 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696357)

---

> What are the causes for it. If anyone have any doc can you share of doc removal of "tools.jar" expected issues and resolution.

1. Documentation: see [JEP 220: Modular Run-Time Images](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) is the proposal that gave rise to this change. It gives the full rationale ... among other things.
2. Issues: the primary issue is the obvious one: code that relies on the presence of "tools.jar" won't work anymore.  This is a breaking change<sup>†</sup>.
3. Resolution: he way access Java Tools at runtime in Java 9+ is to use the `javax.tools.*`  APIs in the `java.compiler` module.  **This will entail some code rewriting.**  For examples; see

   - [Create a java class dynamically and compile and instantiate at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60664816)
   - some of the answers to [what is tools.jar replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638550).

<sup>† - AFAIK, the "tools.jar" file is not *specified* as being part of the pre-Java 9 Java platform.  It is not mentioned in the JLS or JVM spec, or (AFAIK) in the pre-Java 9 javadocs.  It is "just an implementation detail".  Depending on implementation details makes your code more susceptible to breakage when those details change.  The fact that there was no straight-forward alternative (then) doesn't change that.</sup>

---

> Is tools.jar is added in higher versions and what are they.

No.  It isn't.

Comment: Actually, the APIs did not change and even most of the non-API classes are still present. So I would not call this a breaking change, only software insisting on the presence of the specific file `tools.jar` is causing trouble. The [`javax.tools` package is part of the official standard API since Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/?javax/tools/package-summary.html#package_description); the vendor specific packages (`com.sun.source. …`) from the same Java version also still exist.